# Can't bind a class from VM to View in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, view

I have a class that represent the current state of some controls on UI depending on the case of user actions:

```
public class CanDoAbility
{
    public bool CanAdd { get; set; }
    public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
    public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
    public bool CanCancel { get; set; }
    public bool CanPrint { get; set; }
    public bool CanSave { get; set; }
    public bool CanEditFields { get; set; }

    public CanDoAbility()
    {
        CanAdd = true;
        CanDelete = true;
        CanEdit = true;
        CanCancel = false;
        CanPrint = true;
        CanSave = false;
        CanEditFields = false;
    }
}
```

Then, I made an instance of it in the ViewModel, As:

```
public CanDoAbility ViewCanDoAbility { get; set; }
```

And initiated it in the ViewModel contructor (I implement BindableBase in ViewModel):

```
public MyView(){
ViewCanDoAbility = new CanDoAbility();
InitiateCanDoAbility();}
```

Also, in ViewModel, I added:

```
OnPropertyChanged(() => ViewCanDoAbility.CanEditFields);
```

Finally, bind it to the UI using Binding in XAML. As:

```
<Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding ViewCanDoAbility.CanEdit}"/>
```

**The problem is:**

The value of **ViewCanDoAbility** is changing inside the ViewModel as I checked. But, inside the View isn't. How to solve this, becuase I am going to use this class in many ViewModels in my application.

Btw:
I tried to create the same properties inside the ViewModel directly, and it worked.

Comment: I think you are missing the propertychange on the ViewCanDoAbility.

Comment: I missed to mention it in my question, but I did have it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already deriving from the abstract class **BindableBase**, you just need to call the set property. So instead of `public bool CanEdit { get; set; }`

Do this in your code and check if its working.

```
private bool canEdit;

public bool CanEdit
{
    get { return canEdit; }    
    set { SetProperty(ref canEdit, value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I re-write CanDoAbility class, and it is working now. :)

Comment: That's good. If you think my answer is correct, you could select it as the right answer.